# Saber método de compresión usado en fichero tar

Tags: python, archlinux

Necesito saber el método de compresión de un fichero tar, sea *gz*, *bz2*, *xz*, *tar* o *zstd*. Por la extensión no me sirve porque los ficheros son renombrados a *.tar.xz* o *.tar.gz* sin importar el método usado.

**Ficheros:**

- core.db.tar.gz
- extra.db.tar.gz
- community.db.tar.gz
- multilib.db.tar.gz
- archcraft.db.tar.xz
- chaotic-aur.db.tar.xz

Estas son las bases de datos de los repositorios de archlinux, los cuales contienen la lista de todos los paquetes disponibles. Tengo una función para llevarlos a json que con el repositorio oficial funciona perfecto, los repositorios de terceros usan los métodos de compresión de su preferencia.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Yo tengo entendido que el archivo no indica en ninguna parte su tipo fuera de la extension. Se me ocurre hacer que el programa "adivine" por prueba y error a partir del formato del archivo.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Como no hay código en la pregunta, sólo aplica un comentario: eso se identifica normalmente con los magic numbers en el header del archivo. si corres `file` en la terminal, lee esos magic numbers y te da una buena suposición de qué tipo es.

Comment: Tal como en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10937350/1545868), podrías probar la librería de 3ros [Python-Magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic)

Answer (score 2):

En la mayoría de distribuciones unix tienes el comando `file` que puedes aplicar a un fichero así:

```
file nombre_de_archivo
```

Este comando examina los primeros bytes del fichero y los compara con una base de datos de comienzos típicos (también llamados *magic numbers*). En base a ellos puede adivinar de qué tipo es el fichero en la mayoría de los casos. Si no encuentra el comienzo en su base de datos usa otros heurísticos (por ejemplo, si encuentra que todos los bytes corresponden a caracteres ascii, concluirá que se trata de un archivo de texto plano, y también es capaz de detectar el encoding en caso de que haya bytes no-ascii).

Si todos sus heurísticos fallan y no es capaz a deducir qué contiene el fichero, imprimirá finalmente "data". Esto suele ocurrir cuando el contenido del fichero ha sido encriptado por un algoritmo que no deja pistas en su inicio.

Ejemplo:

```
$ file mi_fichero_misterioso.x
mi_fichero_misterioso.x: gzip compressed data, last modified: Mon Sep 12 19:05:08 2022, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 378880
```

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente esta no es una respuesta valida, pero puede proporcionarte un acercamiento. (Además necesitaba poner unas imagenes para explicar)

Generalmente los primeros bytes de un archivo indican los tipos, debes abrir esos ficheros con un editor hexadecimal y ver si con tus casos (gz, bz2, xz, tar o zstd) esto pasa igual, yo no pude probar porque no tengo archivos de ese tipo.

Por ejemplo, yo abro un pdf:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un PNG
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya con esto, en python, abres el archivo en binario y verificas el tipo